# How do I position this text in a certain way?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Yesterday I asked a question about aligning some text next to the top of the image, and it worked. But right now I'm even more stuck so I decided to create a JSFiddle:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d72pu95n/7/)

Here's an image of what I am trying to achieve:

[image: Image 1]

In the jsfiddle you have to make the HTML window a bit bigger to see a correct size. It also has to be mobile friendly, but I will work on that later. If you have any suggestions, though, that would be great!

I have to enter some code to use JSFiddle, so here's a quick view of my HTML:

```
                <aside class="previewPost" id="HTMLPreview">
                <article>
                    <div id="imageDiv">
                        <img src="img/avatar.png" alt="Avatar"  width="150" height="150" id="imageHTML"/>
                        <div id="personDiv">
                            VOORNAAM + ACHTERNAAM (AGE)
                        </div>
                        <div id="workDiv">
                            Beroep
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="headerDiv">
                        VOORNAAM schreef om Datum
                    </div>

                    <div id="postDiv">
                        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
                        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate 
                        velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
                    </div>      
                </article>
            </aside>
```

Edit: So I totally forgot to say where I am actually stuck.

I'm stuck at letting the orange box always stay beneath the image with the correct width (Not further than the right side of the image) and not letting the red box go into the yellow one. I want the text in the red box not go through the red border on the left side. I hope that explains it. Thanks for your time.

**Edit 2:**

I've decided to go with the solution of "Naeem Shaikh", and I updated my JSFiddle. Please take a look at it.

This is the new problem:

[image: Image 3]

As you see, when I do not use spacebar text can go into the orange zone, or the text from the orange zone will go into the red zone. This is not too big of an issue but if someone with an extremely long name starts using this website, the post will look messed up and I do not want that to happen. Is there some way to give, for example,  the black box (Image 1) an infinite length or something? Or maybe  some kind of text wrapping is required?

How do I fix this?

Comment: So which part are you actually stuck on?

Comment: @jbutler483 I'm dumb, I forgot to add that! I'm going to add that in right now!

Comment: Please mark Naeems answer as correct and open a new question for the new problem that arises

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change your html structure a little bit. see this http://jsfiddle.net/d72pu95n/5/ put the `personDiv` and `workDiv` inside the `imageDiv`

```
                     <div id="imageDiv">
                            <img src="img/avatar.png" alt="Avatar"  width="150" height="150" id="imageHTML"/>
                            <div id="personDiv">
                              FirstName + Lastname (AGE)
                            </div>

                            <div id="workDiv">
                             Work
                            </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you. There were some other answers but this one works quite well. Now I have some more problems, though. I added them into my post. Could you take a look at it, @Naeem Shaikh ?

Comment: The question isn't answered yet, as I said. I updated my post with more information

Comment: @S.tenBrinke.. see this http://jsfiddle.net/d72pu95n/8/ does this help.. i will edit my answer accordingly

Comment: It kinda works. The imageDiv works perfectly, but the postDiv still has trouble lining up correctly. When a line is too long, it will just place itself beneath the imageDiv and ruin the entire block. I will work on this later, I have struggled with this for now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

updated the fiddle. 
the key is, use the name div and work details div inside the image div like this:-

```
<div id="imageDiv">
    <img src="http://illinois.edu/assets/images/content/overview/coolstuff/cellphonewallpaper/cellphone_wallpaper_new/240x320/alma_240x320.jpg" alt="Avatar"  width="150" height="150" id="imageHTML"/>
    <div id="personDiv">FirstName + Lastname (AGE)</div>
    <div id="workDiv">Work</div>
</div>
```

fiddle example here http://jsfiddle.net/d72pu95n/4/